# Node.js when trying to access Google Spreadsheets

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, discord.js

I'm trying to get a Discord bot to access a Google Spreadsheet, but this error keeps appearing and I can't work around it, I'm following this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UGN6EUi4Yio) and did everything up until the point where the program is ran. Any ideas how to solve this? Thank you in advance.

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot set property 'jwtClient' of undefined
  at useServiceAccountAuth (Z:\GitHub\discordBot\node_modules\google-spreadsheet\lib\GoogleSpreadsheet.js:60:20)
  at internal/util.js:297:30
  at new Promise (<anonymous>)
  at useServiceAccountAuth (internal/util.js:296:12)
  at accessSpreadsheet (Z:\GitHub\discordBot\sheets\sheets.js:8:45)
  at Object.module.exports.run (Z:\GitHub\discordBot\comandos\duvida.js:51:5)
  at Client.<anonymous> (Z:\GitHub\discordBot\index.js:63:21)     
  at Client.emit (events.js:311:20)
  at MessageCreateHandler.handle (Z:\GitHub\discordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
  at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (Z:\GitHub\discordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
```

My sheets.js file:

```
const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require('google-spreadsheet');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const creds = require('./client_secret.json');

async function accessSpreadsheet(){
  const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('1klBj2ZSk-IaDAT-w8kUKzmLw-o5oAk9otZL6xh1vnks');
  await promisify(doc.useServiceAccountAuth)(creds);
  const info = await promisify(doc.getInfo)();

  const sheet = info.worksheets[0];
  console.log(`Title: ${sheet.title}`);
}

module.exports.accessSpreadsheet = accessSpreadsheet;
```

Comment: What is the file of `client_secret.json`? Is this for the service account?

Comment: @Tanaike exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my understanding:

- You want to retrieve the title of the 1st tab in the Spreadsheet using a module of `google-spreadsheet`.
- `client_secret.json` is the credential file of the service account.
- You have already been able to use Sheets API.

If you are using the latest version of `google-spreadsheet` (in the current stage, it's `google-spreadsheet@3.0.10`.), how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require("google-spreadsheet");

const creds = require('./client_secret.json');

async function accessSpreadsheet() {
  const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('1klBj2ZSk-IaDAT-w8kUKzmLw-o5oAk9otZL6xh1vnks');
  await doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds);
  await doc.loadInfo();
  const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[0];
  console.log(`Title: ${sheet.title}`);
}

module.exports.accessSpreadsheet = accessSpreadsheet;
```

#### Note:

- When `client_secret.json` is not for the service account, an error of `No key or keyFile set` occurs. Please be careful this.
- When an error of `The caller does not have permission` occurs, please share the Spreadsheet with the email of the service account.

#### Reference:

- [node-google-spreadsheet](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet)

Comment: OK! I got it to work! Thank you so much, i looked at the reference and chaged a few things until it finally gave the error that for some reason my Google Sheets API was disabled for this project.